# Disable copy and paste using DOMPDF

Tags: php, dompdf

Is there a way to disable copy and paste of the document generated using **DOMPDF** in PHP?

I like to generate a pdf in my website and I also like to prevent the users to copy and paste the content. Is that possible with the dompdf library?

Comment: I tried that function (setEncryption) and it just set a password to the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DOMPDF, to prevent the resulting pdf from copying (copy and paste), just use `setEncryption` without the parameters

So the code (I have tested, 100% work) is:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');


// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->get_canvas()->get_cpdf()->setEncryption();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream('output.pdf');

?>
```